# delphi 7 - using NotXor penmode for resizing rectangles

Tags: delphi, canvas, resize

I made an application that lets you create a rectangle and resize it however you want but it has a problem.

Whenever I want to draw a new rectangle on an existing one [image: this] happens.

Here is the code for the application :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  xstart,ystart,oldx,oldy,click1,lastx,lasty,copyrect_click:integer;
  in_workspace,click_bol,copyrect_bol:boolean;
  destrect,sourcerect:trect;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  image1.Canvas.pen.Width:=10;
  image1.Canvas.Pen.style:=psSolid;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
click_bol:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
if click_bol then
begin
  xstart:=x;
  ystart:=y;
  oldx:=x;
  oldy:=y;
  image1.Canvas.pen.mode:=pmnotxor;
  image1.canvas.rectangle(xstart,ystart,oldx,oldy);
  click1:=click1+1;
  in_workspace:=true;
  if click1 mod 2=0 then
  begin
    image1.canvas.Pen.mode:=pmCopy;
    image1.Canvas.Rectangle(xstart,ystart,x,y);
    in_workspace:=false;
  end;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
if (in_workspace=true) and (click_bol=true) then
  begin
  image1.canvas.Rectangle(xstart,ystart,oldx,oldy);
  image1.canvas.Rectangle(xstart,ystart,x,y);
  oldx:=x;
  oldy:=y;
  end;
end;

end.
```

I suspect it's because of the NotXor penmode and as you can see from the code I tried to change it to Copy penmode when it draws the actual rectagle but to no avail.

How can I improve this code in order not to have the rectangles change color then I draw them one on another?

Comment: This isn't the way to draw sizing rectangles. If the underlying image has colours that match your rectangle pen then the results are rather underwhelming. Instead draw the image underneath, and then draw the rectangle on top. XOR pen was perhaps useful with graphics performance found on machines 30 years ago. Today, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't think that you really understand what you are doing and why it works (sort of). I think that you have dug up some code from somewhere and are trying to migrate it. All those global variables are a bad sign.

(You also have no mouse-up function - so what you have published will never produce the image you have shown.)

So, what does it do? Well, the canvas background is white and the pen is black (these are default values that you don't change) so if you XORed them the result would actually be white - it would appear to do nothing (unless you changed the pen colour to white), and the NotXOR makes it black. The original program I am guessing used XOR as that was more normal in older programs.

However, these days graphics have greatly improved, and, as David Heffernan says, better to just draw on the old background, and as you progress your program to using colours, this will become more important.

This shows the equivalent to what you are trying to achieve using this method.

Notice that there is much less code. I have removed the button click - it is just a waste of time. Better to put that in the mouse-down event. I have also not dealt with right mouse click etc. (but then, neither did you).

```
unit Unit10;

interface

uses
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Vcl.Grids, Vcl.Buttons, VCL.ExtCtrls,
  System.Classes;



type

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    fSave : TPicture;
    xstart,ystart:integer;
    click_bol:boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fSave := TPicture.Create;
  image1.Canvas.pen.Width:=10;
  image1.Canvas.Pen.style:=psSolid;
end;

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  xstart:=x;
  ystart:=y;
  fSave.Assign( image1.Picture);
  click_bol:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if Click_bol then
  begin
    image1.Picture.Assign( fSave );
    image1.Canvas.pen.Width:=10;
    image1.Canvas.Pen.style:=psSolid;
    image1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    image1.Canvas.Rectangle(xstart,ystart,x,y);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  click_bol := FALSE;
end;

initialization

end.
```

Comment: well yes, you are right. I did dig up the code from somewhere cause I had no idea how to do the resizing thing (i'm a beginner) but I did try to understand it more or less. The code I posted is just a part of a bigger paint application so that's why there is a button : to mimic the application as much as possible. 
Then again, everytime I post something I get bashed but at least now I learned that it's not always good to declare almost all the variables globally.
Anyway, thank you for the code and I'll try to understand it as much as possible.

Comment: @eulaurD the old code is tricky to understand because it uses various mathematical tricks to overcomes limitations of the hardware at the time. What I have given is much simpler. When you click the mouse copy the current image and make a note of one corner. As you move the mouse, repaint the saved image and draw the new temp shape on it. Modern graphics are optimised for this sort of operation.